# Using the Check class, add the code to have the Checks sorted by checkNumber

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

Using the `Check` class, add the code to have the `Checks` sorted by `checkNumber`.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Check implements Comparable {

    private int checkNumber;
    private String payTo;
    private Date date;
    private float amount;

    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        //Insert code here

    }

    public int getCheckNumber() {
        return checkNumber;
    }

    public void setCheckNumber(int checkNumber) {
         this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
    }

    public String getPayTo() {
        return payTo;
    }

    public void setPayTo (String payTo) {
         this.payTo = payTo;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate (Date date) {
         this.date = date;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount (float amount) {
         this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

My solution is below, but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone help me with the solution?

```
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    if(this.checkNumber == arg0.checkNumber)
        return 0;
    else
        return this.checkNumber > arg0.checkNumber ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what you mean by "doesn't work", but reading your code, I'm assuming you get a compilation error.

The reason for this is because the code you were given has not specified a type for the comparable, so it doesn't know what type you even want to compare it to.  It will use `Object` by default, which does not (by design) know a thing about `Check`'s fields and methods.

The following modification is the best solution:

```
public class Check implements Comparable<Check> {

    public int compareTo(Check arg0) {/* ...*/  }
}
```

This will force you to compare this to other `Check`'s only and make arg0 a `Check` object, rendering its fields and methods available to you.

Should the parameters of the problem you were given not allow you to modify the provided code, then the (very very distant) second best solution is:

```
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    Check other = null;
    if(arg0 instanceof Check)
        other = (Check)arg0;
    // Other checks.
}
```

This adaptation would *technically* work for your problem given the stipulation that you are not allowed to modify the provided code, but is otherwise not at all recommended, as the contract for Comparable wants the type of object you wish to compare against to be specified, and not specifying it can introduce problems.

In fact, I'd say you are fully allowed to tell the person who gave you this problem that they are a terrible person for giving you a problem with this mistake in it, because not specifying a Comparable type is a really bad practice.  Especially if they're teaching you how to program.

Comment: Yes thats the error. And yes this is the code give with no further instructions, so there is not even a constructor or something that i can use or something thats why i am confused.

Comment: The lack of constructor isn't a problem (at least technically, it is kind of a stylistic faux pas), you can initialize an instance with `new Check()` and populate fields with the setters since no other constructor exists.  For the Comparable thing, you may wish to read up on [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) and the [Comparable Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).